# Android base64 hash mismatch with server side hash using C# script

Tags: c#, android, ios

I am creating base64 hash using HMAC SHA256 in my Android application. and  send it on server for match  with server side hash.
Following [this](http://jokecamp.wordpress.com/2012/10/21/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#java) tutorial.

Working Android code:

```
 public String getHash(String data,String key) 
 {

    try 
    {
       String secret = key;
       String message = data;

       Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacMD5");
       SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacMD5");
       sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

       String hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
       System.out.println(hash);
       return hash;
 }
 catch (Exception e){
     System.out.println("Error");
 }
```

}

server code is in C# script and its as per below

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Test
{
      public class MyHmac
      {
           private string CreateToken(string message, string secret)
           {
                secret = secret ?? "";
                var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
                byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
                using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
                {
                     byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
                     return Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

but hash key generated at android side is not match with server side and below is objective c code which generate same as C# code

objective c code:

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>

    @implementation AppDelegate

    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
    {
        NSString* key = @"secret";
        NSString* data = @"Message";

        const char *cKey = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
        CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
        NSData *hash = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];

        NSLog(@"%@", hash);

        NSString* s = [AppDelegate base64forData:hash];
        NSLog(s);
   }

   + (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData 
   {
       const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
       NSInteger length = [theData length];

       static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

       NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
       uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

       NSInteger i;
       for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
           NSInteger value = 0;
           NSInteger j;
           for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
               value <<= 8;

               if (j < length) {  value |= (0xFF & input[j]);  
           }  
       }  
               NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;  output[theIndex + 0] = table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
               output[theIndex + 1] = table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
               output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6) & 0x3F] : '=';
               output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0) & 0x3F] : '=';
   }

   return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 
 }

 @end
```

please help me to sove out this issue,
Thanks in advance.

I have solved this issue by changing HmacSHA256 to HmacMD5 and its give same hash value as given by C# code.

I have updated my question with working code. check it

Comment: Note that since iOS 7 and OSX 10.9 there is a method to encode and decode Base64: `base64EncodedDataWithOptions:` and `base64EncodedStringWithOptions:`.

Comment: What values are you getting for Android, see the output for Objective-C in the psudo answer. It seems that this is only an Android question.

Comment: @Zaph in Objective-c getting output length 24 and at android side its 42.

Comment: See my answer, it has an output length of 42. Provide the output from the NSLog statements in your example, edit your question and add those values.

Comment: The code posted for Objective-C creates a 42 byte Base64 result. If you are getting something different then the code you are running is not the same as the code posted. SHA256 produces 32 bytes (256 bits) and Base64 encodes that into 42 ASCII bytes. MD5 produces 16bytes (128 bits) and Base64 encodes that into 24 ASCII bytes.

Comment: @Zaph  ohh yes, at objective c side also used MD5 for getting same key as C# side.

Answer (score 0):

In android `secret.getBytes` may get UTF-16 bytes, check the length of the result. In general separate such functions out into separate statements for easier debugging.

Not the answer, rather a demonstration of a simpler Obj-C implementation and provides the hash and Base64 vaules:

```
NSString* key = @"secret";
NSString* data = @"Message";

NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSData *dataData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSMutableData *hash = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, keyData.bytes, keyData.length , dataData.bytes, dataData.length, hash.mutableBytes);

NSLog(@"hash: %@", hash);

NSString* s = [hash base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"s: %@", s);
```

Output:

```
hash: <aa747c50 2a898200 f9e4fa21 bac68136 f886a0e2 7aec70ba 06daf2e2 a5cb5597>   
s: qnR8UCqJggD55PohusaBNviGoOJ67HC6Btry4qXLVZc=
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is an encoding issue.
In one sample you specify the string should be encoded using ASCII when converting the string to a byte array. In the other sample you do not specify an encoding.
If the default encoding is anything other than ASCII that means the byte arrays will be different, leading to different hash results.

Comment: Probably not the encoding, the example has ASCII characters. But it could be that the Android `getBytes` returns UTF-16 (unichar) bytes.

Comment: Use the same encoding on both platforms. eg; on the .NET side use UTF8Encoding instead of ASCIIEncoding, then on the Java side use secred.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8). That will mean both sides will use the same encoding so you will get the same byte array from the text. (or use UTF16, or any other encoding you like, just make sure it is the same on both systems).

Comment: @BrianO''Byrne curruntly i used same encoding at both side and that was ASCIIEncoding. so I am unble to find the issue.